# How to call directive method in app component

Tags: directive

I am able to call directive method within normal component that I generated through @viewChild. But could not call directive method within appComponent.

I have created on NgLoopStateDirective directive and there is one method i.e test

```
test(){
 return 'hi test function';
}
```

I need to call this method in app.component.ts. I am doing this by this way 
 app.component.ts

```
@ViewChild(NgLoopStateDirective) directive;
public callDirective(){
  this.directive.test();
}
```

this throw en error 
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'test' of undefined